# Como altero a cor dos ícones do status bar no Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout

Preciso alterar as cores dos ícones igual o *app* da Google Agenda, como mostra na imagem abaixo:

[image: Aplicativo Google Agenda]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi que no Material Design tem as opções `colorPrimaryDark` mas não tem para mudar a cor dos ícones. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta você definir como `true` a propriedade [`windowLightStatusBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowLightStatusBar) no estilo dentro do arquivo `styles.xml`. Desta forma, os ícones serão alterados para cinza (sem cores personalizadas). Veja:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

**Nota**: Isso só funciona a partir da **API 23**. Por exemplo: `values-v23/styles.xml`. Ou podes inserir a propriedade `targetApi` sendo como 23 desta forma:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
```

[image: Roman Nurik Google+ post]

<sup>Imagem do Roman Nurik [Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/4WBSonAZxt1)</sup>

Também é possível fazer isso programaticamente, veja:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
    if (shouldChangeStatusBarTintToDark) {
        decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    } else {
        decor.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
    }
}
```

Observe que primeiramente é necessário verificar a versão do SDK que está a usar.

Comment: perfeito Ack Lay, irei verificar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, porém teria alguma opção para definir a cor dos icones ao invés do padrão cinza ?

Comment: @afnascimento somente ligth e dark pelo que já li. Acho que customizar demais é ruim, porque acaba saindo muito do padrão.

Comment: Entendido @AckLay, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: como faço para validar ? obg